# How do I only change the texture coords once I've rendered a VBO?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

When I render a cube it looks like this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3,  GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordsBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordsAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

I want to change the texture coords only and I'm not changing the vertices or indices.
My question is do I have to resend the vertex data and index data to render this cube again or can I just send the new texture coords?  And if I can just send the new texture coords what OpenGL calls do I need to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordsBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

which means bind the buffer again and call `glBufferData` on it.

You can also make a new vbo with the texture coordinates and set that as the attribute buffer by calling `glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordsAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);` with it bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Comment: So I would do glBindBuffer and glBufferData to copy the new coords?  And then keep the same steps as above for rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the data in an existing buffer using `glBufferSubData()`:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordsBuffer);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, textureDataSizeInBytes, textureData);
```

If you update the data frequently, you should choose the *usage* parameter of the initial `glBufferData()` call accordingly:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureDataSizeInBytes, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

It is legal to call `glBufferData()` each time you want to modify the data. But it is potentially much less efficient, because it implies allocating a new buffer object each time.

Note that the *data* argument of `glBufferData()` can be specified as NULL in this case. When used this way, it will only allocate memory for the data, with the expectation that you will later specify the data itself with calls to `glBufferSubData()`.